# Exposing the current combo selection index for the CGridCellCombo class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cgridctrl

For several years I have been using the [`CGridCellCombo`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/500/Using-comboboxes-in-the-MFC-Grid-Control) class. It is designed to be used with the [`CGridCtrl`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control).

Several years ago I did make a request in the comments section for an [enhancement](https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1849059/Item-Index.aspx) but I got no replies.

The basic concept of the `CGridCellCombo` is that it works with the text value of the cell. Thus, when you present the drop list it will have that value selected. Under normal circumstances this is fine.

But I have places where I am using the combo as a droplist. In some situations it is perfectly fine to continue to use the text value as the go-between.

But is some situations it would have been ideal to know the actual selected index of the combo. When I have a droplist and it is translated into 30 languages, and I need to know the index, I have no choice but to load the possible options for that translation and then examine the cell value and based on the value found in the array I know the index.

It works, but is not very elegant. I did spend a bit of time trying to keep track of the selected index by adding a variable to `CInPlaceList` and setting it but. I then added a wrapper method to the `CGridCellCombo` to return that value. But it didn't work.

I wondered if anyone here has a good understanding of the `CGridCellCombo` class and might be able to advise me in exposing the `CComboCell::GetCurSel` value.

I know that the `CGridCtrl` is very old but I am not away of another flexible grid control that is designed for MFC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this to be the simplest solution:

```
int CGridCellCombo::GetSelectedIndex()
{
    int iSelectedIndex = CB_ERR;

    CString strText = GetText();
    for (int iOption = 0; iOption < m_Strings.GetSize(); iOption++)
    {
        if (strText.CollateNoCase(m_Strings[iOption]) == 0) // Match
        {
            iSelectedIndex = iOption;
            break;
        }
    }

    return iSelectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value that is transfered back to the `CGridCtrl` is choosen in `CInPlaceList::EndEdit`. The internal message `GVN_ENDLABELEDIT` is used, and this message always use a text to set it into the grid.

The value is taken here via `GetWindowText` from the control. Feel free to overwrite this behaviour.

The handler `CGridCtrl::OnEndInPlaceEdit` again calls `OnEndEditCell`. All take a string send from `GVN_ENDLABELEDIT`.

When you want to make a difference between the internal value and the selected value you have to manage this via rewriting the Drawing and selecting. The value in the grid is the `GetCurSel` value and you have to show something different... There isn't much handling about this in the current code to change.

### More information

The key is  `CInPlaceList::EndEdit()`. There is a call to `GetWindowText` (`CInPlaceList`  is derived from `CComboBox`), just get the index here. Also in `CGridCellCombo::EndEdit` you have access to the `m_pEditWnd`, that is the `CInPlaceList` object and derived from `CComboBox`, so you have access here too.

Comment: I don't really want to change the mechanics of the class. It should still return the text value. I would just like to know (in addition) what the selected index was. I was just hoping to hold the index inside the `CGridCellCombo` object so that when I access the cell object itself I could call a method to return the active selection index.

Comment: It is possible. As I wrote. The key is  CInPlaceList::EndEdit() and CGridCellCombo::EndEdit. There is a call to GetWindowText (CInPlaceList  ist derived from CComboBox), just get the index here. Or in CGridCellCombo::EndEdit you have access to the m_pEditWnd, that is the CInPlaceList object and derived from CComboBox. Added this to my answer.

Comment: I can place a breakpoint in the `CInPlaceEdit::EndEdit` and intercept that but I can't intercept the `CGridCellCombo::EndEdit` handler. In addition, in my case, `CInPlaceEdit::EndEdit` is being called by `CInPlaceList::OnKillFocus`. I can't trap it from `CGridCellCombo::EndEdit`

Comment: Out of interest, do you think it is possible that we can just add a method to `CGridCellCombo` that takes the current cell text value and iterates the member array of strings? The droplist index would match. The default could be -1 (for when the combo cell is editable). This way I don't need to maintain a variable to hold the selected index.